# Where is SQL Analyzer/Profiler

Tags: sql-server-2014

I haven't used SQL Server in many years and installed SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition on my Windows 8 development machine today. I'm unable to find the SQL Analyzer tool which from other posts seems to have been renamed to Profiler. What word should I search on to find this application (Windows Search) or is there a simpler way to find it?

I'm not sure if this matters, but I started off with the Express edition of of 2012, couldn't find the tools either and then upgraded to the 2014 Standard Edition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tools -> Profiler. Simple as that. It has always been there. Express editions don't include Profiler. So maybe you should have un-installed before upgrading.

Comment: Mitch, thank you, but I can't even find "Tools".  Windows 8 isn't showing me any applications to even start.  I've launched MMC and added the SQL Server snap in and it shows the server as running, but no tools menu there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install SQL server with the install that includes SQL Server Management studio. The Advanced pack contains everything including full text indexing if I remember.
If you've installed the standard edition you might have it already - look for SQL Server Management Studio in your apps.
If not you can download it separately.

Comment: Thank you all.  I re ran the installer and was able to find a choice to install Management Tools.  After doing that, I found Management Studio was installed and was able to find the Query Profiler.  Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Express with Tools is the minimum version that comes with Profiler. That would be the case for both SQL Server (...) 2012 and 2014. There is Profiler for Db Engine and Profiler for Analysis Services and the former is going away after SQL 2016 as described on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=sql.120).aspx

"... announcing the deprecation of SQL Server Profiler for Database Engine Trace Capture and Trace Replay. These features will be supported in the next version of SQL Server, but will be removed in a later version. The specific version of SQL Server has not been determined. The Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace namespace that contains the Microsoft SQL Server Trace and Replay objects will also be deprecated. Note that SQL Server Profiler for the Analysis Services workloads is not being deprecated, and will continue to be supported."